# Rails 4 - Setting up Delayed Job for Batch Import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm building an marketplace app on Rails 4 where sellers can import product listings via a csv file. I want to use delayedjob to handle the import method so it processes in the background.

I've looked at the documentation and a railscast on the topic. The instructions seemed very simple but it looks like I'm missing something. I installed the gem, created the delayed jobs table and migrated db.

I ran `rake jobs:work` but this hangs. I get a msg saying `starting job worker` and it stays like that till I hit ctrl+C. I want this as a setting so the delay happens everytime the import process is run.

Here is my import method. I added `delay` per the docs. When I try to upload a file, I get the invalid CSV error. So two questions - 1) how do I get it to work? I don't see the job in the delayed jobs table and 2) How do I set it up so the user gets notified of the invalid format only if there is an error.

```
  def import
    begin
      Listing.delay.import(params[:file], params[:user_id])
      redirect_to seller_url, notice: "Products are being imported. Please check back in a few minutes."
    rescue
      redirect_to seller_url, notice: "Invalid CSV file format."
    end
  end
```

My view is just a form to select the file and a submit button to import.

Are there better ways to do this without delayed jobs? I need to do something because I get timeout messages on heroku when I load large files (even just 100+ rows because there are images being fetched via URI)

Comment: I don't know answer to your question, but just wanted to say that it is very bad idea to rescue without giving exact error class. It will say "Invalid CSV..." for any exception that will be raised, no matter if it concerns your import or not. And actually in current code it won't catch even import error as it will be executed in separate delayed job process, so you will have "Invalid CSV..." notice for everything else then import errors...

Comment: @Lucas How would I change code so I can let users know there is an error in the file format? Without delayed job, I was getting invalid error only when there was a problem with the file.

Comment: No, unfortunately you weren't, this was just the coincidence. Asuuming that csv library raises ```MyCsvLibrary::InvalidFileFormat```, you could write ```rescue MyCsvLibrary::InvalidFileFormat```. Otherwise you will catch any error inheriting from ```StandardError```. Which is a lot of error types: http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/09/06/rubys-exception-hierarchy/

Comment: Answering second question, this is not so easy thing to do. Remember that background job is used to perform operations in separate process so you would have to send that information to some place accessible to frontend (so i.e. your database / redis / some other store) and use ajax to check if there was an error or success every few seconds. This is the trade off when using background jobs unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, so without background jobs, how do I avoid getting timeout errors when I load large files?

Comment: Another, simpler way which I just thought about would be to check csv file format without importing anything (if it is of course possible) and then if format is ok, pass it to delayed job. But if there will be some errors on import itself we are getting to same problem of course.

Comment: Using background jobs has its trade offs, but still it is most general solution. Without background jobs you have to make your import fast which would be probably far more difficult (or imossible) to implement than communication between background jobs and frontend.

Comment: Also I have just read your updated description and first thing you should do is removing rescue part. You are probably getting some error which you cannot see because it redirects in case of any error. Than please come back with real error.

Comment: I removed rescue. I tried uploading one row of data with the `delay` call. I get an error `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`. Name is one of the columns in my model which the file imports to. Without the `delay` the upload goes through fine. Am I using delay incorrectly?